# SQL Aggregate Function over partitions

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I'm relatively new to SQL but have learned some cool stuff. I'm getting results that don't make sense. I've got a query with several subqueries and what-not but I have a windowed function that isn't working like I'm expecting.

The part that isn't working is this (simplified from the 300 line query):

```
SELECT AVG(table.sales_amount) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY table.month, table.sales_rep, table.department)
FROM table
```

The problem is that when I pull the data non aggregated I get a value different (107) than the above returns (95).

I've used windowed functions for `COUNT` and `SUM` and they work fine, but `AVG` is acting strangely. Am I missing something about how this works with `AVG`?

The subquery that `table` is a standin for looks like:

sales_rep, month, department, sales_amount

`1, 2017-1, abc, 125.20
1, 2017-2, abc, 120.00
2, 2017-1, def, 100.00
...etc`

Working out of Sql Server Management studio

SOLVED: I did finally figure it out, the results i was joining this subquery to had the sales rep multiple times in a month selling objects A&B which caused whoever sold both to be counted twice. whoops, my bad.

Comment: You would have to show sample data and the results you are getting.  Your expectation isn't right, but it is not clear where the misunderstanding is.

Comment: I agree… this doesn't sound right.  But, what database platform, and whats your data like — do you have any NULLs?  What else is in that 300 line query?

Comment: Which dbms?????

Comment: added into original post, but working out of SSMS from microsoft

Comment: @GordonLinoff so this won't work to get dept avgs by month?

Answer (score 0):

The results that you get should be the same values as in:

```
SELECT AVG(table.sales_amount) 
FROM table
GROUP BY table.month, table.sales_rep, table.department;
```

Of course, the rows will be different.  You need to match up the three key columns.

Based on your sample data, it looks like the partitioning keys uniquely define each row.  Perhaps you really intend:

```
SELECT AVG(table.sales_amount) OVER () as overall_average
FROM table;
```

EDIT:

For the departmental average:

```
SELECT AVG(table.sales_amount) OVER (partition by table.department) as department_average
FROM table;
```

Comment: what i'm trying to get is the avg for the dept, for the month. to compare the individual against dept avg over a period of time. I don't think the `OVER ()` would help that much

Answer (score 0):

After some bruteforcing of potential errors I finally figured out the issue. I was joining that subquery to the another which had multiple instances of a `sales_rep` in a given month (selling objects a & b) which caused the average of those with sales of both objects to be counted twice instead of once.

so sales rep 1 sold objects a & b which made his avg count as 66% of the dept avg instead of 50%, and sales rep 2 count only 33%.